# SQL: Get number rows, increment each insert?

Tags: sql-server

Given the following code:

```
Insert into dbo.RowNumberTest (id, custID)
Select (select ISNULL(MAX(id)+1, 1) from  dbo.RowNumberTest), customer.id
From customer
```

The desired result is that each row will have inserted the number of rows + 1.

The current code just reads the number of rows and then inserts the same number without incrementing it for each insert. To clarify, the code current inserts data like this:

```
1    10032
1    10033
1    10034
...
```

What I want is

```
1    10032
2    10033
and so on.
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: What is the purpose of dbo.RowNumberTest? You can get the same functionality from an IDENTITY column on the customer table itself. But, I'm assuming you have a reason for not using IDENTITY.

Comment: Use an identity column or a sequence. Using `max()` to "generate" new ids is not multi-user safe and does not scale. Or just use `row_number()` to generate numbers on the fly if they don't have to be "in-sync" with the existing IDs

Comment: @Ellesedil: The test table is just for testing and dev but it represents the table data is going into. I cannot set the key to autoincrement (don't ask why). I'm not using anything that I don't know about because I don't know about it :)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I basically need to recreating autoincrementing because the silly software that created this table made a nonkey column autoincrement. They do not need to link to the inserted data but they need to increment according to previous rows.

Comment: Too bad. `CustomerID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY` would far and away be the best solution for you.

Comment: Then use `row_number()` or a sequence

Comment: Not being allowed to use an identity when clearly an identity is the right way to do this screams of some strange requirement by business, or maybe this is homework and it is from the professor.

Comment: No, it's a business system put out by a computer company you know. One column is autoincrement but not pk. The other colunm is PK but not autoincrement.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
Insert into dbo.RowNumberTest (id, custID)
Select  Row_Number() over(order by NewID()),customer.id
From customer
```

[**Demo Here**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/615902/1)

Comment: Why does this work when you specify NewID() in the over clause?

Comment: `see` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186734.aspx
`And`
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx

you'll understand everything.

Comment: Awsesomesauce. So we basically don't need any real number in the over clause because we don't care. We just need to generate a new incremented number each Row_Number() and the over() is required, NewID() just says, "here, have another number" and when combined, it's like Voltron and just gives us a new number. How would I do that if I wanted to base this on the highest number in that id column? Meaning "I want to start at the highest number +1 and increment from there"